# How to find & change texts outside of tags with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have a file like this:

```
words1 outside of a Tag <tag1> words2 inside of tag1 </tag1> words3 outside of a Tag
```

I want to extract strings outside of `tag1` and change it to something like this with beautifulsoup:

```
changed word1 <tag1> words2 inside of tag1 </tag1> changed word3
```

how can i replace words out of tags with beautifulSoup ?

Answer (score 2):

Text elements are also considered child elements of the parent element.

If you find `tag1`, you can find the text before and after in the attributes `.previousSibling` and `.nextSibling`. Or, you can find the parent tag, and then select the appropriate children.

Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# assuming BeautifulSoup 4

doc = """
words1 outside of a Tag <tag1>words2 inside of tag1</tag1>
words3 outside of a Tag
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')
tag = soup.find('tag1')
tag.previousSibling.replaceWith('changed word1 ')
tag.nextSibling.replaceWith(' changed word3')

print(soup)
```